# Is django's UploadedFile interchangeable with python File type?

Tags: python, django

Im looking to parse an uploaded gpx file using gpxpy, and I have an InMemoryUploadedFile. Is this interchangeable with python file? Or do I need to write to disk?

Ive checked the django source code but couldnt see it reference the base type

The code I want to execute is -

```
import gpxpy
import gpxpy.gpx

# Parsing an existing file:
# -------------------------

gpx_file = open('test_files/cerknicko-jezero.gpx', 'r')

gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)

for track in gpx.tracks:
    for segment in track.segments:
        for point in segment.points:
            print 'Point at ({0},{1}) -> {2}'.format(point.latitude, point.longitude, point.elevation)

for waypoint in gpx.waypoints:
    print 'waypoint {0} -> ({1},{2})'.format(waypoint.name, waypoint.latitude, waypoint.longitude)

for route in gpx.routes:
    print 'Route:'
    for point in route.points:
        print 'Point at ({0},{1}) -> {2}'.format(point.latitude, point.longitude, point.elevation)
```

Comment: What happens when you try using your `InMemoryUploadedFile` object in place of a `file` object? Does it work?

Comment: Its a byte stream - so 'b<a>hello</a> - so from what Ive read I will need to write to file then reload, unless theres a neat trick?

Comment: gpx_file can be a string (so convert it to string) or anything that has a read() method.

Comment: Thanks - i had to UTF-8 decode it - and that was the problem